# Class record structure only recording last input

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, records

I am trying to create an array Record structure using a class in Python 3. This is my code:

```
class Books():
    def __init__(self):
        self.title=""
        self.author=""

newbooks=[Books()]*4

for i in range(4):
    newbooks[i].title=input("Input title of the book")
    newbooks[i].author=input("Input author of the book")


print(newbooks[0].title)
```

However, the final line will always print the final input rather than the first. Every element in my array stores the final input and not the one entered on the correct counter. I'm a little confused as to why; any help?

Comment: In short, change the initialization of `newbooks` to `newbooks=[Books() for _ in range(4)]`.

Comment: Is this still classed as a Record structure, or would this be turning more into a 2D array? for my classwork I have to use record structures and not 2d arrays.

Comment: It results in the same structure as yours, the difference is with `newbooks=[Books() for _ in range(4)]` you get 4 distinct Book objects; in your case you had 1 Book object and 4 references to it.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much. My last question is do I need to bother with the def init() part of the class?